# Angular/FastAPI 422 Unprocessable Entity error

Tags: javascript, python, angular, fastapi

I am having issues and receiving 422 response errors from my FastAPI server. I understand the request it is recieving does not match the pydantic model it is expecting, but I don't know why.

Here is my request model:

```py
@authenticate.post("/token", response_model=Token)
async def login_for_access_token(
        form_data: OAuth2PasswordRequestForm = Depends()):
    print(form_data)
    user = authenticate_user(
        form_data.username,
        form_data.password
    )
    print(f'User @ 104 = {user}')
    if not user:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
            detail="Incorrect username or password",
            headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
        )
    access_token_expires = timedelta(minutes=login_utility.get_expiration_time())
    access_token = create_access_token(
        data={"sub": user['username']}, expires_delta=access_token_expires
    )
    return {"access_token": access_token, "token_type": "bearer"}
```

I am sending the request from an Angular app using:

My payload:

```json
{"username": blah, "password":password}
```

```py
postTypeRequest(url: string, payload: any) {
    console.log(payload)
    console.log(this.REST_API_SERVER+url)
    return this.httpClient.post(
      this.REST_API_SERVER+url, payload).pipe(map(res => {
      return res;
    }));
  }
```

I am not having any issues sending the request via Postman. I am a greenhorn using JavaScript/Angular and I am unsure of what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/security/simple-oauth2/#get-the-username-and-password):

> OAuth2 specifies that when using the "password flow" (that we are
> using) the client/user **must** send a `username` and `password` fields as
> **`form`** data.
>
> ... the `username` and `password` must be sent as `form` data
> (so, **no** `JSON` here).
>
> ....`OAuth2PasswordRequestForm` is a class dependency that declares a `form` body with:
>
> - The `username`.
> - The `password`.
> - ...

Hence, you **should be sending the credentials as `Form` data**. Have a look at these AngularJS-related topics: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37359844/send-formdata-using-angularjs-http-service), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33975071/angularjs-send-form-data) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46444807/send-form-data-using-angularjs-not-working), as well as these FastAPI-related topics: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73662576/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75188418/17865804).

Answer (score -1):

Shouldn't the payload be: {username: "blah", password: "password"}

Comment: payload = {"username": blah, "password":password}.  Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: That's invalid JSON.

Error: Parse error on line 1:
{"username": blah, "password":pas
-------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'

Comment: ```{
 "username": "tinkerbell",
 "password": "passsword"
}```. Is this incorrect?  This is the format being returned by formbuilder.group.  Are extra steps required?