# Secure route in FastAPI

Tags: python, flask, fastapi

I have a Flask-based backend REST API and I want to migrate to FastAPI. However, I am not sure how to implement secure routes and create access tokens in FastAPI.
In Flask, we have methods from the flask_jwt_extended library such as:

@jwt_required() decorator for secure routes

create_access_token() function for creating JWT tokens.
Does FastAPI have a similar feature or capability, or how can I implement this in FastAPI?
Thank you in advance.
Here is an example implementation of secure route and create access token in Flask:

```
import hashlib
import traceback
from datetime import timedelta
from http import HTTPStatus
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_jwt_extended import JWTManager, jwt_required, get_jwt_identity, create_access_token

app = Flask(__name__)
jwt = JWTManager(app)
app.config["JWT_SECRET_KEY"] = "very-secret1234567890"
app.config["JWT_ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRES"] = timedelta(minutes=15)
app.config["JWT_REFRESH_TOKEN_EXPIRES"] = timedelta(days=30)
host = "localhost"
port = 5000
test_password = "test_password"
db = [
    {
        "username": "test_user",
        "email": "test_email.gmail.com",
        "password": hashlib.sha256(test_password.encode()).hexdigest()
    }
]


@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    try:
        json_data = request.get_json()
        email = json_data.get("email")
        password = json_data.get("password")
        if not email or not password:
            response = jsonify(error="'email' and 'password' are required")
            return response, HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST
        # Check if email exists in DB
        user_result = [user for user in db if user["email"].lower() == email.lower()]
        # Check if the password is correct
        encoded_password = hashlib.sha256(password.encode()).hexdigest()
        if not user_result or user_result[0]["password"] != encoded_password:
            response = jsonify(error="Wrong credentials")
            return response, HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST
        user = user_result[0]
        # Generate JWT token and return it
        access_token = create_access_token(identity=user["username"])
        response = jsonify(username=user["username"], token=access_token)
        return response, HTTPStatus.OK
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
        print(traceback.format_exc())
        response = jsonify(result={"error": "Server error"})
        return response, HTTPStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR


@app.route('/secured_page', methods=['GET'])
@jwt_required()
def __create_participant():
    try:
        response = jsonify(message="You are logged in as {}".format(get_jwt_identity()))
        return response, HTTPStatus.OK
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
        print(traceback.format_exc())
        response = jsonify(result={"error": "Server error"})
        return response, HTTPStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host=host, port=port, debug=True)
```

Comment: btw [JWT is not very secure](https://paragonie.com/blog/2017/03/jwt-json-web-tokens-is-bad-standard-that-everyone-should-avoid)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redirect to login page if user not logged in using FastAPI-Login package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73630653/redirect-to-login-page-if-user-not-logged-in-using-fastapi-login-package)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use libs like python-jose for JWT functionalities, but you have to implement `jwt_required` and `create_access_token` by yourself, for example

create_access_token

```
from jose import JWTError, jwt
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def create_access_token(data: dict):
    to_encode = data.copy()
    expire = datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(minutes=15)
    to_encode.update({"exp": expire})
    encoded_jwt = jwt.encode(to_encode, SECRET_KEY, algorithm=ALGORITHM)
    return encoded_jwt
```

jwt_required (instead of a decorator, you create a function and set it as a dependency of your route)

```
from fastapi import Depends, HTTPException, status
from fastapi.security import OAuth2PasswordBearer
from jose import JWTError, jwt

oauth2_scheme = OAuth2PasswordBearer(tokenUrl="token")

async def jwt_required(token: str = Depends(oauth2_scheme)):
    credentials_exception = HTTPException(
        status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
        detail="Could not validate credentials",
        headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
    )
    try:
        payload = jwt.decode(token, SECRET_KEY, algorithms=[ALGORITHM])
        username: str = payload.get("sub")
        if username is None:
            raise credentials_exception
    except JWTError:
        raise credentials_exception
    user = get_user(username=username)
    if user is None:
        raise credentials_exception

@app.get('/secured_page', dependencies=[jwt_required])
def __create_participant():
...
```