# FastAPI_Login RedirectResponse after authorization fails

Tags: python, redirect, fastapi, setcookie

I have a simple login form that is opened using a `GET` request, and the user submits the form with a `POST` request. After successful authentication, I redirect the user to the main page of my web application using a `RedirectResponse` object.

However, despite the successful redirection, the user is not authorized on the main page, as if the authentication cookie was **not** set. There are no error messages displayed.

Here's the code for my login route:

```
@router.post('/login')
def login(response: Response, 
          data: OAuth2PasswordRequestForm = Depends(), 
          db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    email = data.username
    password = data.password

    user = db.query(DbUser).filter(DbUser.email == email).first()

    if not user:
        # you can return any response or error of your choice
        raise InvalidCredentialsException

    if not Hash.verify(user.password, password):
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND,
            detail='Incorrect password')

    token = manager.create_access_token(
        data={'sub': email}
    )
    resp = RedirectResponse(url='/post/stat/all',status_code=status.HTTP_302_FOUND)
    manager.set_cookie(response, token)
    return resp
```

However, if I change `resp = RedirectResponse(...` to `resp = 'ok'`, then everything works fine - just without a URL redirection.

Tried also with no luck:

```
return templates.TemplateResponse("/login/success.html",{"request": request})
```

What would be the issue and a way to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to specifying the `Response` object instead of `RedirectResponse` in the `manager.set_cookie()` method. As per your example:

```py
@router.post('/login')
def login(response: Response,
          ^^^^^^^^ 
          ...):

    ...

    resp = RedirectResponse(url='/post/stat/all', status_code=status.HTTP_302_FOUND)
    ^^^^
    manager.set_cookie(response, token)
                       ^^^^^^^^
    return resp
```

This is why returning `OK` or anything other than a custom `Response` object works, as you noticed. Hence, since you are instead returning a custom `RedirectResponse`, you should set the cookie for that `RedirectResponse` instance:

```py
@router.post('/login')
def login(data: OAuth2PasswordRequestForm = Depends(),
          db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    ...

    resp = RedirectResponse(url='/post/stat/all', status_code=status.HTTP_302_FOUND)
    manager.set_cookie(resp, token)
    return resp
```

A complete working example can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73662576/17865804) as well.