# How to combine FastAPI security (auth) and Bootstrap5

Tags: python, fastapi, bootstrap-5

My question is that how should I combine FastApi [security](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/security/oauth2-jwt/) and Bootstrap5? Unfortunately I'm really stuck on this part... I read about storing the jwt token in a cookie and use that for auth but I have no clue how to implement it. Could you give me a solution?

What I want to achive:

- login on the frontend
- after auth, redirect to about page

Below there are my `.py` and `.html` files.

[image: sample]

**main.**`py`

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from app import about, auth, login

app = FastAPI()

app.include_router(about.router)
app.include_router(auth.router)
app.include_router(login.router)
```

**about**.`py`

```
from fastapi import APIRouter, Request
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
from app import auth

router = APIRouter()

templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")

@router.get("/about", response_class=HTMLResponse, tags=["About"])
async def about(
        request: Request,
        current_user: auth.Annotated[auth.User, auth.Depends(auth.get_current_active_user)]
):

    context = {
        "request": request,
        "current_user": current_user
    }

    return templates.TemplateResponse("about.html", context)
```

**login**.`py`

```
from fastapi import APIRouter, Request
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
from app import auth

router = APIRouter()

templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")

@router.get("/login", response_class=HTMLResponse, tags=["LogIn"])
async def login(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("login.html", {"request": request})
```

**auth**.`py`

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone
from typing import Annotated, Union

from fastapi import Depends, APIRouter, HTTPException, status
from fastapi.security import OAuth2PasswordBearer, OAuth2PasswordRequestForm
from jose import JWTError, jwt
from passlib.context import CryptContext
from pydantic import BaseModel


# to get a string like this run:
# openssl rand -hex 32
SECRET_KEY = "09d25e094faa6ca2556c818166b7a9563b93f7099f6f0f4caa6cf63b88e8d3e7"
ALGORITHM = "HS256"
ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_MINUTES = 30


fake_users_db = {
    "johndoe": {
        "username": "johndoe",
        "full_name": "John Doe",
        "email": "johndoe@example.com",
        "hashed_password": "$2b$12$EixZaYVK1fsbw1ZfbX3OXePaWxn96p36WQoeG6Lruj3vjPGga31lW",
        "disabled": False,
    }
}


class Token(BaseModel):
    access_token: str
    token_type: str


class TokenData(BaseModel):
    username: Union[str, None] = None


class User(BaseModel):
    username: str
    email: Union[str, None] = None
    full_name: Union[str, None] = None
    disabled: Union[bool, None] = None


class UserInDB(User):
    hashed_password: str


pwd_context = CryptContext(schemes=["bcrypt"], deprecated="auto")

oauth2_scheme = OAuth2PasswordBearer(tokenUrl="token")

router = APIRouter()


def verify_password(plain_password, hashed_password):
    return pwd_context.verify(plain_password, hashed_password)


def get_password_hash(password):
    return pwd_context.hash(password)


def get_user(db, username: str):
    if username in db:
        user_dict = db[username]
        return UserInDB(**user_dict)


def authenticate_user(fake_db, username: str, password: str):
    user = get_user(fake_db, username)
    if not user:
        return False
    if not verify_password(password, user.hashed_password):
        return False
    return user


def create_access_token(data: dict, expires_delta: Union[timedelta, None] = None):
    to_encode = data.copy()
    if expires_delta:
        expire = datetime.now(timezone.utc) + expires_delta
    else:
        expire = datetime.now(timezone.utc) + timedelta(minutes=15)
    to_encode.update({"exp": expire})
    encoded_jwt = jwt.encode(to_encode, SECRET_KEY, algorithm=ALGORITHM)
    return encoded_jwt


async def get_current_user(token: Annotated[str, Depends(oauth2_scheme)]):
    credentials_exception = HTTPException(
        status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
        detail="Could not validate credentials",
        headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
    )
    try:
        payload = jwt.decode(token, SECRET_KEY, algorithms=[ALGORITHM])
        username: str = payload.get("sub")
        if username is None:
            raise credentials_exception
        token_data = TokenData(username=username)
    except JWTError:
        raise credentials_exception
    user = get_user(fake_users_db, username=token_data.username)
    if user is None:
        raise credentials_exception
    return user


async def get_current_active_user(
    current_user: Annotated[User, Depends(get_current_user)]
):
    if current_user.disabled:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Inactive user")
    return current_user


@router.post("/login/token", tags=["LogIn"])
async def login_for_access_token(
    form_data: Annotated[OAuth2PasswordRequestForm, Depends()]
) -> Token:
    user = authenticate_user(fake_users_db, form_data.username, form_data.password)
    if not user:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
            detail="Incorrect username or password",
            headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
        )
    access_token_expires = timedelta(minutes=ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_MINUTES)
    access_token = create_access_token(
        data={"sub": user.username}, expires_delta=access_token_expires
    )
    return Token(access_token=access_token, token_type="bearer")
```

**base**.`html`

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  </head>

  <body>

        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
          <div class="container-fluid justify-content-center">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse flex-grow-0" id="navbarTogglerDemo02" >
                <ul class="navbar-nav text-center">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('about') }}">About</a>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('login') }}">LogIn</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>


        <div class="container mt-4 mb-4">
          <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
             <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-8">

                 {% block content %}

                 {% endblock %}

             </div>
          </div>
        </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

**about**.`html`

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
    
{% block content %}

    <form method="POST">
        <input
            type="text"
            id="about"
            name="about"
            class="form-control"
            />
        <br/>
        <div align="center">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save</button>
        </div>
    </form>

    <br/>

{% endblock %}
```

**login**.`html`

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
 
{% block content %}

    <form method="POST">
        <input
            type="text"
            id="username"
            name="username"
            class="form-control"
            placeholder="Enter Name"
            />

        <br />

        <input
            type="password"
            id="password"
            name="password"
            class="form-control"
            placeholder="Enter Password"
            />

        <br/>

        <div align="center">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">LogIn</button>
        </div>

    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74060795/17865804) answer your question?

Comment: Related answers can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73155629/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73963905/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77009220/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74268404/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73137093/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76104800/17865804). You might also find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73662576/17865804), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74407063/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73599289/17865804) helpful as well.