# POST request works from postman/swagger, but not from React Native (422 Unprocessable Entity)

Tags: javascript, react-native, http-post, fastapi

I have a POST request to a FastAPI project which works fine in postman and swagger UI for the same request.

[image]

When I try to use the fetch/axios method in React native for the same request, I get 422 Unprocessable Entity error.

```
const onLoginPressed = async () => {
    const headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/text',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type",
      'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST,PATCH,OPTIONS',
    }
    const response = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/***/v1/***/***-token", {
        'method': "POST",
        'mode': 'no-cors',
        'withCredentials': true,
        'headers': headers,
        'body': JSON.stringify({
          username: '***@**.com',
          password: '****',
        }),
      })
    const json = await response.json();
    console.log(json);
}
```

[image]

I tried POST method to send login data and expected to get an access token / secret key.
Expected output

[image]

I am not sure why this is not working in React native code. I initially saw recommendations to put await in front of the fetch since the call is async but this did not fix the errors(see the above code).

I have the following CORS in the backend:

```
# BACKEND_CORS_ORIGINS is a JSON-formatted list of origins
    # e.g: '["http://localhost", "http://localhost:4200", "http://localhost:3000", \
    # "http://localhost:8080", "http://local.dockertoolbox.tiangolo.com"]'
    BACKEND_CORS_ORIGINS: List[AnyHttpUrl] = []

# Set all CORS enabled origins
if settings.BACKEND_CORS_ORIGINS:
    app.add_middleware(
        CORSMiddleware,
        allow_origins=[str(origin) for origin in settings.BACKEND_CORS_ORIGINS],
        allow_credentials=True,
        allow_methods=["*"],
        allow_headers=["*"],
    )
```

What am I missing?

Comment: In addition to the link provided above, please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73963905/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75041731/17865804). You might find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73662576/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75188418/17865804) helpful as well.

Answer (score 2):

API expects form data, so building a request goes something like this

```
let formData = new FormData()
formData.append('username', '***@**.com')
formData.append('password', '****')

const response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/***/v1/***/***-token', {
   method: 'POST',
   body: formData
})
```