# FastAPI RedirectResponse to route in ApiRouter in different file

Tags: redirect, fastapi

In a FastAPI application, I want to use user authentication like described here:

https://fastapi-login.readthedocs.io/advanced_usage/

The application uses an APIRouter for the user authentication part in a different file.

This is in my **main.py**:

```
app = FastAPI(title="Some API")

app.include_router(auth_router)

from starlette.responses import RedirectResponse
from routers.authenticate import NotAuthenticatedException


@app.exception_handler(NotAuthenticatedException)
def auth_exception_handler(request: Request, exc: NotAuthenticatedException):
    # Redirect the user to the login page if not logged in

    return RedirectResponse(auth_router.url_path_for("/login"))
```

and in **authenticate.py**

```
class NotAuthenticatedException(Exception):
pass

@auth_router.post('/login')
def login(...):
       ...
    return response


@auth_router.get('/protected')
def protected_route(user=Depends(manager)):
    return {"message":"You are an authenticated user!", "user":user.username}
```

I left some code out for brevity, since the user login itself works. When a user (that is not logged in) tries to access `/protected` the `NotAuthenticationException` is thrown as expected and the exception handler in **main.py** is called.

But the redirect never gets to the `/login` in **authenticate.py**. I am pretty sure that this is because the `RedirectResponse` tries to redirect to a `/login` within the same file, which is **main.py**.

Since there is no `/login` defined, nothing happens.
So my question is, how do I set the url in the `RedirectResponse` correctly so that it targets `/login` in **authenticate.py**?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73662576/17865804) answer your question?

Comment: No, since the redirect happens within the same file and there is no APIRouter in use.

Comment: It did answer my question. Sorry, i did not see the difference in the RedirectResponse arguments when I first read it. I changed RedirectResponse(auth_router.url_path_for("/login")) to RedirectResponse(url = "/login") and it works. Thanks a lot!