# FastAPI: User authentication using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, authentication, fastapi

I have two endpoints, /login and /index. The /login is for authentication and getting an access_token. The /index is protected and user should login first.

After authentication, the /login sends the access token to the client. The client should be redirect to the /index page after receiving an access token.

It is the code:

```
oauth2_scheme = OAuth2PasswordBearer(tokenUrl="login")

@app.get("/index")
async def root(
       request: Request,
       current_user: Annotated[User, Depends(oauth2_scheme)]
):
   return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {"request": request})

@app.post("/login")
async def login(
   request: Request,
   data: Annotated[OAuth2PasswordRequestForm, Depends()],
):
   user = authenticate_user(data.username, data.password)
   if not user:
       raise HTTPException(...)
   access_token = create_access_token(...)
   response.set_cookie(key="access_token", value=access_token, httponly=True)
   return Token(access_token=access_token, token_type="bearer")
```

It is the client form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Login</h1>
<form id="loginForm" >
   <table>
       <tr>
           <td>
               <label for="username">Email:</label>
           </td>
           <td>
               <input type="text" id="username" name="username" required>
           </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td>
               <label for="password">Pass Code:</label>
           </td>
           <td>
               <input type="text" id="password" name="password" required>
           </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td></td>
           <td>
               <button type="submit" style="margin-top: 15px">Submit</button>
           </td>
       </tr>
   </table>
</form>
<script>
   document.getElementById("loginForm").addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       fetch("/login", {
           method: "POST",
           body: new FormData(event.target)
       })
           .then(response => {
               if (response.ok) {
                   return response.json();
               } else {
                   throw new Error('Failed to authenticate');
               }
           })
           .then(data => {
               window.location.href = '/index';
           })
           .catch(error => console.error("Error:", error));
   });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This code does not work because of lacking of the authentication header. I get this error:
{"detail":"Not authenticated"}

The test in /docs works because it sends the access token in the Authorization header. This command works:

```
curl -X 'GET' \
  'http://127.0.0.1:8000/index' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer A_VALID_TOKEN '
```

I do not know how I should handle the client side. I am not sure if I should send another fetch for the /index and get the html content and assign it to the body section. I do not know what is the best practice. Maybe I can use RedirectResponse from fastapi.response. I am not sure if it is a good practice or not. /login should send back an access token and not a html code I think.

**Edit**
The access token is stored in cookie.

**Edit 2**
I added a hidden form and used a post method to reach the index endpoint

```
<form action="/index" id="token_form" method="post" style="display: none;">
    <label>
        <input type="text" id='token' name="token" value="YOUR TOKEN" hidden>
    </label>
</form>
```

In the back-end I did not use Depence feature for now like

```
@app.post("/index")
async def root(
        request: Request,
):
    frm = await request.form()
    return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {"request": request})
```

But ideally I am looking for a way to use the endpoint protection through dependency injection.

```
@app.post("/index")
async def root(
        current_user: Annotated[User, Depends(oauth2_scheme)]
):
```

Comment: I highly doubt that OAuth redirection step would ever happen on the client side. `window.location.href = '/index';` is where you lose the token. Instead of the `fetch` magic you would do an actual form post, then the server should check password, etc. and then respond with a HTTP 302 to the actual page, also providing a code or the token itself. Still, if you really want this local redirect, either store the token somewhere (cookie, localstorage, whatever), or pass it as an url parameter.

Comment: You might find the following answers helpful: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73662576/17865804), as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75188418/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73599289/17865804)

Answer (score 0):

You can send a bearer token with `fetch`:

```
fetch('your/url', {
  headers: {Authorization: 'Bearer ' + yourtoken}
})
   .then(data => {
       //some code
   })
```

But this will not redirect. In your `then` you are aiming to redirect, but you have two main options here. Either you have a session id or something stored in the cookies, representing a valid session, in which case there should be no issues with the redirect, or you want to actually send the bearer token with a redirect, in which case you will need to send (and receive) this value as a POST parameter rather than a request header.

I've been researching this for a JWT SSO work and we finally decided to use a POST parameter in order to pass a JWT with the redirect rather than passing it as a request header.

EDIT

Example of the `form` idea:

```
<form action="/index" method="post" style="display: none;">
    <hidden name="token" value="YOUR TOKEN">
</form>
```

and you should submit this form when the login succeeded. Maybe you do a login with the first `fetch` call you have, receive the token, set the value of your token field in this second form and `submit()` the form object.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit. For the first method, fetch the index page, after fetching the html of index I should assign it to the body content of the current page. Am I write or not?
Can you please tell me more about the second method POST. 
In the first fetch I got the access token and I can save it in a cookie for example. Then I need to redirect to another page which need authentication. I am trying to solve authentication in html page. either way is fine

Comment: @Karimai the fetch was merely an illustration that you can pass bearer tokens. You can do full postbacks like you suggested, but it seems a very hacky solution to me and I recommend not to do it, you may have some downloaded scripts and initialized listeners that will not behave properly. The approach I'm suggesting is to have a `form` inside the HTML you have (it could be hidden if you want to auto-submit) and that `form` would be a POST form for the sake of security and your token would be a named field inside of it, so it will be a POST parameter when you submit the form.

Comment: @Karimai and the POST request would therefore be sent to your server which would receive your token as one of the POST parameters and handle it accordingly, the `action` of the form pointing to your index.

Comment: @Karimai I edited my answer to provide further details.

Comment: I added a hidden POST form and send it if I get a token from login page. Thanks, it works! Still I am eager to know if I can use Dependency injection in fastapi.

Comment: @Karimai I'm not an expert with FastAPI, but I found this article, so it seems to be possible: https://medium.com/@himanshu.sharma.for.work/step-by-step-guide-to-implementing-oauth-authentication-in-fastapi-8291a3184f46 . If my answer helped you solve your problem, then you might consider accepting it as the correct answer.

Answer (score -1):

You're on the right track. The typical flow for handling authentication and redirecting after successful login is as follows:

1. User submits credentials to the /login endpoint.
2. Server validates credentials and generates an access token.
3. Server responds with the access token.
4. Client receives the access token and stores it securely (usually in a cookie or local storage).
5. Client initiates a redirect to the protected /index endpoint, including the access token in the Authorization header.
6. Server verifies the access token and serves the protected content.

Here's how you can modify your client-side code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Login</h1>
<form id="loginForm">
   <table>
       <tr>
           <td>
               <label for="username">Email:</label>
           </td>
           <td>
               <input type="text" id="username" name="username" required>
           </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td>
               <label for="password">Pass Code:</label>
           </td>
           <td>
               <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required>
           </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td></td>
           <td>
               <button type="submit" style="margin-top: 15px">Submit</button>
           </td>
       </tr>
   </table>
</form>
<script>
   document.getElementById("loginForm").addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       fetch("/login", {
           method: "POST",
           body: new FormData(event.target)
       })
           .then(response => {
               if (response.ok) {
                   return response.json();
               } else {
                   throw new Error('Failed to authenticate');
               }
           })
           .then(data => {
               // Store the access token securely (e.g., in a cookie or local storage)
               document.cookie = `access_token=${data.access_token}; path=/`;

               // Redirect to the protected /index endpoint
               window.location.href = '/index';
           })
           .catch(error => console.error("Error:", error));
   });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This modified client-side code includes a change to use type="password" for the password input field and stores the received access token in a cookie named access_token. It then redirects the user to the protected /index endpoint.

On the server side, you should modify the /index endpoint to validate the access token from the request headers using the oauth2_scheme. Make sure you include the access token in the Authorization header when making requests to the protected endpoint.

This approach aligns with best practices for handling authentication and authorization in web applications.

Comment: thanks. I have problem here
               // Redirect to the protected /index endpoint
               window.location.href = '/index';
with this redirection, I think I can not send authentication header. Could you please kindly correct me? How it sends the access token in the header?

Comment: You should avoid storing the access token using `localStorage` or the `document.cookie` JavaScript API. You should rather let the server set the cookie including the `HttpOnly` flag. Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73599289/17865804) for more details on that subject.